# Cannot find some ithems from kivymd library

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am a begginer, I try to programme app for my school graduation.. but in my kivymd library it looks like some items are missing. When I check it manually, the others buttons are there.
e.g. in kivymd I havent any toolbar folder,and so on...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Stanko/PycharmProjects/pythonProject0.2/main.py", line 6, in <module>
     from kivymd.uix.button import MDRoundImageButton, MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial
 ImportError: cannot import name 'MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial' from 'kivymd.uix.button' (C:\Users\Stanko\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py)
```

Comment: Version of KivyMD library?

Comment: I have a 102.1 version

Comment: I upgraded it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall kivy and then try again
I was also getting same issues and this worked